# Django user details inline formset to exclude fields and ensure 1 form of inline filled

Tags: python, django

I want to exclude a field in a CustomUser modelform which should be part of the BaseInlineFormset. What I tried:

```
class CustomUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = CustomUser

    class Meta:
        exclude = ('send_creation_mail',)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_department = self.cleaned_data['department'] 
        cleaned_report_to = self.cleaned_data['report_to'] 
        # count = 0
        if cleaned_department is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Department is mandatory')

        if cleaned_report_to is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Report to is mandatory')

class CustomUserFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = CustomUser
    form = CustomUserForm

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False

    def clean(self):
        # get forms that actually have valid data
        count = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            try:
                if form.cleaned_data and not form.cleaned_data.get(
                    'DELETE', False):
                    count += 1
                    if form.cleaned_data.get('department') is None:
                        raise forms.ValidationError('Department is mandatory')
                    if form.cleaned_data.get('report_to') is None:
                        raise forms.ValidationError('Reporting is mandatory')

            except AttributeError:
                # annoyingly, if a subform is invalid Django explicity raises
                # an AttributeError for cleaned_data
                pass
        if count < 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('At least one detail is mandatory')


class CustomUserInline(admin.TabularInline):
    formset = CustomUserFormSet
```

If I use CustomUserForm in CustomUserInline class, it definitely excludes the attribute 'send_creation_mail' but while saving the User form, it throws up an exception:

```
POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/dms/auth/user/add/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I want to ensure that atleast 1 inline form is filled before saving the User details in the django admin auth. Using form = CustomUserForm, has no effect in the class CustomUserFormSet as the CustomUserForm displays all the fields of the Model(which should exclude 'send_creation_mail'). I need detailed code as to where there is a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.clean()` does not return `self.cleaned_data` (it needs to return `cleaned_data` or raise `ValidationError()`).